# Finding if values in multiple columns greater than constant in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This is how my data frame (df) looks:

```
id,activity_date,status01_1,status01_2,status02,status03_01,status03_02, status04
1,2020-12-09 22:13:16,0,0,3560,0,0,0
1,2020-12-10 01:02:33,8327,0,0,0,0,0 
1,2020-12-11 01:02:33,0,0,230,0,0,0
```

I would like to find if any of the status 01 and 03 columns are over a constant value of 2000 and set a another column (flag) to say the value was greater than 2000.
So in the input above rows, 1 and 2 will satisfy the condition but not 3.

The solution I can think of is to filter the data frame to have only  status 01 and 03 columns in a new dataframe and use a complicated np.where clause to set a flag.

```
df1 = df[[status01,status03]]
df1[more_than_2000] = np.where((df1['status01_01'] >= 2000) | (df1['status01_02'] >= 2000) | ...), 1,0)
```

What is a much better way of doing this?

Comment: Your data is ragged, 4,3,4 datapoints on the respective lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try:

```
df1['ge_2000'] = df1.filter(like='status01').max(axis=1).ge(2000).astype(int)
```

Or

```
df1['ge_2000'] = df1.filter(like='status01').ge(2000).any(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
      id  activity_date          status01_1    status01_2    status02  status03_01    status03_02       status04    ge_2000
--  ----  -------------------  ------------  ------------  ----------  -------------  -------------  -----------  ---------
 0     1  2020-12-09 22:13:16             0             0        3560  0              nan                    nan          0
 1     1  2020-12-10 01:02:33          8327             0           0                 nan                    nan          1
 2     1  2020-12-11 01:02:33             0             0         230  0                                     nan          0
```

---

**Update**: for the extra question in comment:

```
s = df.filter(like='status')

df.join(s.groupby(s.columns.str.split('_').str[0], axis=1)
  .max().gt(2000).astype(int)
  .add_suffix('_ge2000')
)
```

Comment: like='status01' how do I include like='status03' also in this?

Comment: @Ram Assuming that `like` be accepting a regex, you could use something: `like='status0[1-3]'`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `max()` function here:

```py
col_max = df1[['status01_01', 'status01_02', ...]].max(axis = 1)
df1[more_than_2000] = df1[col_max >= 2000]
```

Comment: Do you mean `max(1)`? Also, your code doesn't seem to run as expected by OP.